# How to use Table.select() in MySQL Connector/C++ 8.0

Tags: c++, mysql, c++11, mysql-connector

According to the documentations here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-cpp/8.0/classmysqlx_1_1abi2_1_1r0_1_1_table.html and here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/sql-crud-functions.html, I need to construct a `ProjectedSearchExprStrList` if I wanna call `mysqlx::Table.select()`.

What does this `ProjectedSearchExprStrList` look like!!!! I cannot find absolutely no example anywhere on the internet. And how does it differ from the `SearchConditionStr in TableSelect.where()`.

Please someone give a complete example of this thing! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ProjectedSearchExprStrList` is defined [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/crud-ebnf-other-definitions.html) (`11.7 Other EBNF Definitions`). `Expression` is defined [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/mysql-x-expressions-ebnf-definitions.html) (`Chapter 12 Expressions EBNF Definitions`). I wasn't able to find `Alias`,  but I guess it should be the same as `ID` as defined in `Chapter 12 Expressions EBNF Definitions` (last link).

Basically, it's pretty much the same you are able to provide with `SELECT <expr> FROM...`. Column names, aliases, etc. Although for computed projections, you probably need to wrap the entire thing in [`mysqlx::expr()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-cpp/8.0/group__devapi.html#ga21018326a03bbb6653e315b6ebb5993b).

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js